# Blender fbx to gltf export gives error

Tags: export, gltf

UPDATE: error solved itself, will leave as reference in case someone in the future comes across something similar.

[image: error message]

Here is the error, i think it has something to do with the lack of animation? However i've tried a few similar models and they have all worked. The fbx model is imported using a plug in https://blendermarket.com/products/better-fbx-importer--exporter, but previously all models have been exported properly too. Any clues/insight/intuition to what this might mean and/or what to check is enough.

Comment: This looks like a crash in the glTF exporter. Can you report it as a bug in the [glTF-Blender-IO Issue Tracker](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues)?  They might ask for a simple Blender project that reproduces the problem.

Comment: interestingly, I left for dinner and came back and reimported the file and it seems to have fixed itself? I absolutely changed nothing and I have also tried doing so numerous times. I guess i'll just hope that others don't come across the same issue.